# PHP: Wrap every 3 in array then place remaining

Tags: php, loops

I have a loop of posts that splits into a list item after every 4 posts. However, I do not want any list item to have less than 3 and no more than 4. Here is my loop:

```
echo '<li class="match">';
  while ( $player_query->have_posts() ) {
    $player_query->the_post(); $i3++; $i5++;

    echo '<span class="team team-' . ( $i5 - 1 ) . '"><span class="team-name">' . get_the_title() . '</span>';
    echo $select . '</span>';

    if ( $i4 === 2 && $count == $i5 && checkNum( $count ) === TRUE  && needBye( $count ) === TRUE ) {
      echo '</li><li class="match bye">';
    } elseif ( 0 == $i3%$i4 && $count != ( $i5 - 1 ) ) {
      echo '</li><li class="match">';
    } else {
      echo '';
    }
  }
echo '</li>';
```

Example of what I have with 10 posts:

```
<li>
  Post 1
  Post 2
  Post 3
  Post 4
</li>
<li>
  Post 5
  Post 6
  Post 7
  Post 8
</li>
<li>
  Post 9
  Post 10
</li>
```

But, what I want is:

```
<li>
  Post 1
  Post 2
  Post 3
  Post 10
</li>
<li>
  Post 3
  Post 4
  Post 5
  Post 6
</li>
<li>
  Post 7
  Post 8
  Post 9
</li>
```

Anyone have any clues to do this? Or, where you can point me? Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Please search for `array_chunk()` in PHP functions...

Comment: Why does Post 3 appear twice?

Comment: It is unclear what the various counters are doing. This would be trivial to answer if it was just a matter of regrouping array items.

Comment: @FrayneKonok: Some of the items have to be reordered into different chunks. This is more than `array_chunk()` can handle.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try Like This
echo '<li class="match">';
$counter = 0;
while ( $player_query->have_posts() ):
$player_query->the_post(); ?>

<span class="<?= ($counter%3 == 0)?'match':''; ?>"></span>

<?php $counter +=1;
endwhile;
echo '</li>';
```